# PHP - mysql_query() inside a static function of a class

Tags: php, class, visibility, global

### The Situation

I have a table in a DB that contains job types, basically defined by a label and a price. I'm trying to do a simple `SELECT * FROM jobtype` but I can't seem to get it to work, although I've use the same block over and over again in the rest of the code. The main difference here, is that it is a singleton trying to execute the function.

The problem is that as soon as I uncomment the line `$rs_job_types = mysql_query($query_job_types, $vtconnection) or die(mysql_error());` the page will stop loading at this particular point in the code.

### The Code

Following is the code of my function `getJobTypes()`:

```
require_once('Connections/vtconnection.php');
class JobTypes extends Singleton{
    static private $job_types;

    public static function getJobTypes(){
        if (self::$job_types == null){
            echo 'DEBUG: For now, $job_types is NULL.'."\n";
            mysql_select_db($database_vtconnection, $vtconnection);
            $query_job_types = 'SELECT * FROM jobtype';
            $rs_job_types = mysql_query($query_job_types, $vtconnection) or die(mysql_error());

            while ($rs_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_job_types)){
                // let the job type identifier in the db be its index in our array
                self::$job_types[$rs_row['id']]['label'] = $rs_row['label']; // job type label
                self::$job_types[$rs_row['id']]['price'] = $rs_row['price']; // job type price
            }
            if (self::$job_types != null) echo 'DEBUG: $job_types has been populated.'."\n";
        }
        return self::$job_types;
    }
}
```

Which I am calling like so:

```
$jt = JobTypes::getJobTypes();
```

Here is my singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton{
    private static $instances = array();

    final private function __construct(){
    }

    final public function __clone(){
        trigger_error('You don\'t clone a singleton!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    final public static function getInstance(){
        $c = get_called_class();
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$c])){
            self::$instances[$c] = new $c;
        }
        return self::$instances[$c];
    }
}
```

I have turned the problem in my head, commented everything inside the `getJobtypes()` function and uncommented step by step. I found out the problem does happen with the `mysql_query()` line, just can't seem to work out why. Is something obviously wrong in my code?

---

### Solved

As suggested here, I used `global $vtconnection,$database_vtconnection;` at the start of my static function and all went smooth. It is not an optimal solution but it pointed out the scope issue which I will now try to resolve.

I also got rid of the singleton pattern.

Comment: What is "the problem"? An error message? I would advise throwing away the Singleton base class and doing it in the JobTypes class. Consider whether you really should be using a singleton here, because most of the time you shouldn't. Singletons are bad for the same reasons that globals are. A simple static function will usually suffice.

Comment: I'll try this in as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the most obvious thing is `$database_vtconnection` `$vtconnection` are defined nowhere in your `getJobTypes` function.  If they're part of the class, you need `$this` (object) or `self` (static) references.  More likely it looks like you're trying to use global variables, in which case you have to pull them into the scope of the function.

[`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) can auto-connect (if `$vtconnection` isn't supplied) but only if it knows how - there's a previous connection (or possible INI config with db/host/user/pass).

To pull them into scope you need to add the line at the beginning of the function:

```
global $vtconnection,$database_vtconnection;`
```

... Or use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal array:

```
mysql_select_db($GLOBALS["database_vtconnection"],$GLOBALS["vtconnection"]);
```

For the record using globals isn't a particularly good solution.

Comment: I only included snippets of the code in my example but I have a seperate vtconnection.php file that I require_once() at the start of the page. I'll make sure it's not a scope issue by trying to echo all the variables I'm using.

Comment: You say the opposite in your question - if that's not the total code of `getJobTypes` then don't say "Following is the code of my function getJobTypes()"

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The getJobTypes() function is complete as you see it here, the vtconnection.php is "required" in the global scope of the page.

Comment: @Justin Huss That still doesn't bring the variables into the `JobTypes::getJobTypes` function